# Expectation and variance in coin flips

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

You win $2^n$ dollars if you flip a tail on the $n^{\text{th}}$ flip, aka $P(X=2^n)=.5^n$ for $n$ from $1$ to infinity.

- Let $Y(x)=x^{\frac{1}{k}}$ for $k > 0$. What is $E[Y(X)]$ and for which values of $k$ does this converge? What property does $Y$ have for these values of $k$?

How would I solve this since $Y(x)$ is not a linear function? I know $E(Y)=aE(X)+b$ if $Y=aX+b$.
Could this apply to this function as well?

Or would I do $E[Y(X)]=\sum{Y(x)}{p_X(x)}$?

- $Y(X)$ has finite expectation if $k = 2$. Find variance.

This means that the random variable $Y$ is discrete since there's finite expectation. so does this mean

$$\mathrm{var}(Y(X))=E[Y(X)^2]-E[Y(X)]^2=E[0.5^2]-0.5^2 $$

- If $Y(x) = \log_2(x)$ how does expectation and variance differ? Is the value larger or smaller?

I'm trying to learn this material ahead of time but I am not fully grasping these concepts. I appreciate any help

Comment: Your calculation of $var(Y(X))$ is incorrect, because $Y(X) \ne 0.5$. You're getting $var(Y(X)) = 0$, which can't be as $Y(X)$ is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

Let us recall the definition of the expectation (for discrete random variables): If $X$ can have only values $x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots$, then its expectation is defined as

$$ \Bbb{E}X = \sum_{i} x_{i} \, \Bbb{P}(X = x_{i}). $$

So if $f(x)$ is a function (in your case, the notation $Y$ is used instead), then working with this definition a little bit yields

$$ \Bbb{E}f(X) = \sum_{i} f(x_{i}) \Bbb{P}(X = x_{i}) \tag{*}$$

This is actually what you have point out in your own question, with a slightly different notation. Now with $f(x) = x^{1/k}$, we can answer to your first question by making the following calculation:

$$ \Bbb{E}X^{1/k}
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (2^{i})^{1/k} 2^{-i}
= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (2^{(1/k)-1})^{i}.$$

This converges if and only if $2^{(1/k)-1} < 1$, or equivalently, $k > 1$.

Now can you demonstrate how to solve the other problems?

**Addendum.** Here I show you how $\text{(*)}$ follows solely from the definition. You need not know how it comes, but rather it is sufficient to know that this is indeed possible.

*Proof of $\text{(*)}$.* Let us enumerate the image of $\{x_{1}, x_{2}, \cdots \}$ under $f$ as $\{ y_{1}, y_{2}, \cdots \}$. Then for each $y_{i}$, there exists a set of indices $J_{i}$ such that $f(x) = y_{i}$ if and only if $x = x_{j}$ for some $j \in J_{i}$. Then
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}f(X)
&= \sum_{i} y_{i} \Bbb{P}(f(X) = y_{i}) \\
&= \sum_{i} y_{i}  \Bbb{P}(X = x_{j} \text{ for some } j \in J_{i})
 = \sum_{i} y_{i} \sum_{j \in J_{i}} \Bbb{P}(X = x_{j}) \\
&= \sum_{i} \sum_{j \in J_{i}} f(x_{j}) \Bbb{P}(X = x_{j})
 = \sum_{j} f(x_{j}) \Bbb{P}(X = x_{j}).
\end{align*}